# The correct way to say someone is interrupting as I'm doing something

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

Is there a phrasal verb/other shorter words for someone who suddenly appears and interrupts?

For example:

> Just as I took the picture, a child appeared in front of the camera
> and blocked the people behind him.

Comment: In this specific example, the entire meaning is conveyed by "A child [photobombed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/photobomb) my picture."

Comment: @randomhead +1 if it had been an answer.